# Is there a way to make prometheus not scrape a pod's port?

Tags: prometheus

I have a pod which exposes two port. One exports metrics via `/metrics` and the other is not.
When I configure prometheus with the following config:

```
- job_name: default_ns
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
      namespaces:
        names:
          - default
```

I see that for each pod, all the ports are being scraped. The port which doesn't have the `/metrics` enabled, is failing the scrape - which is expected.

I'm wondering if there's a way to be more explicit about telling prometheus which ports to scrape (and which not to scrape). I'm not sure this is possible, as per the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#pod) for `pod` roles:

> For each declared port of a container, a single target is generated

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Thanks.